# Google analytics to track url of hosting Iframe content

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

I am hosting a site which offers some contents. Users in my site use this content and embed into their  blogging/private site. SO I want to track all the sites which are embedding my site's content into their site. So how to use google analytics to track parent url via iframe.

Tks
Vil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do something like figure out what the value of `window.top` is and then send that to GA as a `custom dimension`.